# How to get category information for a single product in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I have an item, i.e. with ID=5.

This product is in Category 1, which is named "Category 1".

I want to get the category name by using the ID, or the SKU of Product with ID=5.

How can I do that?

`$_item->getCategory()` doesn't work, unfortunately.

Thanks

Comment: When you say an item you're referring to a product ?

Comment: Yes, I do. I am trying to modify a page based on the order the customer did. From the $order object I do $order->getAllItems(); in order to get the array of the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pid = '5' // product id    
$product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($pid);
$cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
if(count($cats) ){
   $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
   $_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($firstCategoryId);
      return $_category->getName();
 }
```

Comment: Based on the returned value, how can I get the Name of the category?

Comment: check my edited answer. but make sure `5` is the `product_id` and not `item_id`

Comment: NEAT. Will check out and give feedback! :)